# iOS Access only in one array of two dimensional array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want access to one of the array and show all the content of that particular array selected.

This is the code:

**OLD AND WRONG CODE SNIPPET**

```
NSArray *prova = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://i.imgur.com/3IBezow.jpg", nil];

_BIGArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:prova, prova1, nil];


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    cell.gridImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"];

   url = [[_BIGArray objectAtIndex:_idArray]objectAtIndex:_idArray];

    cell.gridImage.associatedObject = url;

    [self.operationManager GET:url
                    parameters:nil
                       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                           if ([cell.gridImage.associatedObject isEqualToString:url])
                           {
                               cell.gridImage.image = responseObject;
                           }
                       } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"Failed with error %@.", error);
                       }];
    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

collectionviewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *BIGArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger idArray;
```

collectionviewcontroller.m

```
 NSArray *prova = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"http://i.imgur.com/3IBezow.jpg", nil];

 NSArray *prova1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"http://i.imgur.com/yE4egi4.jpg", nil];

_BIGArray = @[prova, prova1];

- (AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)operationManager
{
    if (!_operationManager)
    {
        _operationManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
        _operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    };

    return _operationManager;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    cell.gridImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"];

    NSString *url = [_BIGArray objectAtIndex:_idArray];

    cell.gridImage.associatedObject = url;

    [self.operationManager GET:url
                    parameters:nil
                       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                           if ([cell.gridImage.associatedObject isEqualToString:url])
                           {
                               cell.gridImage.image = responseObject;
                           }
                       } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"Failed with error %@.", error);
                       }];
    return cell;
}
```

If i write this line of code:

```
NSString *url = [_BIGArray objectAtIndex:_idArray];
```

I get following error:

```
2014-10-07 05:09:29.444 prova_prj[497:70b] ID: 0
2014-10-07 05:09:29.454 prova_prj [497:70b] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1a9400
2014-10-07 05:09:29.464 prova_prj [497:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1a9400'
```

And my goal is to select the array ( using the index view I get from the previous view) and show all images.
Is it possible in Objective-C? In Java and C# I did it without any major problems.



**SOLUTION**

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [array insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://i.imgur.com/3IBezow.jpg", @"http://i.imgur.com/HyDJrDX.jpg", nil] atIndex: 0];
[array insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://i.imgur.com/yE4egi4.jpg", @"http://i.imgur.com/twc1Ml5.jpg", @"http://i.imgur.com/66V4dhe.jpg", nil] atIndex:1];
```

Then I've changed _BIGArray string of code:

```
_BIGArray = [array objectAtIndex:_idArray];
```

Then I've changed url string of code:

```
NSString *url = self.BIGArray[indexPath.row];
```

Thank you all.

Comment: you can use a for cycle to take all elements from 1 to the end of array... But pheraphs I missed something in your question.

Comment: ...and where is the two dimensional array anyway? because in your code snippet you don't have any, but a simple one-dimensional array only.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is only one array , but since I was going in a hurry I thought that he had taken both, I updated the array

Comment: I suggest you define an array like @[item1, item2, etc]

Comment: @DavideDeFranceschi I tried to define what type of array, and in url access in this method: url = [_BIGArray objecAtIndex: _idArray]. But I get the following error: 2014-10-07 05:09:29.444 prova_prj [497:70b] ID: 0
2014-10-07 05:09:29.454 prova_prj HD[497:70b] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1a9400
2014-10-07 05:09:29.464 prova_prj[497:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1a9400'

Comment: If you want all the elements of an inner array, don't index it!!  If you want all the elements of a given inner array index for all outer array indexes you must use any of several very simple schemes to build a new array.

Comment: first: `array[index]` is faster to type and equal to `[array objectAtIndex:index]`, second try to put a breakpoint at the line that gets the right URL and see if the array is like it should be

Comment: I solved it all now , my fault for not having thought of it before , I wrote in the post resolution

Answer (score 1):

You can access the array as the first element of top array. like

`NSArray *urls = (NSArray *)[_BIGArray objectAtIndex:_idArray];`

Comment: Frankly, if this is not obvious to the OP then he should not be attempting to code in Objective-C.  He needs to learn basic programming concepts first, and Objective-C is not a beginner's language.

Comment: I'm not new to programming but I'm new to Object-C, I program in Java and C # with less difficulty Objective- C

Answer (score 0):

_BIGArray has only one object in it which is prova. I don't see how you can retrieve [1][1] or even [1]. 
You can retrieve `_BIGArray[0][x]` (where x has a range of 0 to prova.count-1) or `_BIGArray[0]` (which will give you the array prova back).

EDIT:

`NSArray *first = _BIGArray[0]` will give you array prova
`NSArray *second = _BIGArray[1]` will give you array prova1.

This should do what you need.

Comment: Actually, his second version has two arrays in it.